# Tortoise SVN creating repository problem

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've a problem with Tortoise SVN on my local machine. I've tried to create repository folder, and got a message:

> Subversion reported an error while creating a repository!
>   Make sure the folder is empty and not write protected.

In fact there is enough disk space, and directory isn't write protected.
My OS is WindowsXP, and I'm logged under administrator user.

Could you advice me how to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: not normal.. are you sure there aren't any hidden files or directories in there? have you tried another directory? have you tried on the commandline with svnadmin create myrepo?

Comment: @stmax: Thanks. Hmm. I've solve my problem, making my repository directory network shared. Is that normal?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The menu is a bit misleading. There are 2 ways to create a new repository with TortoiseSVN:

1. No directory is selected

   - Start in a directory
   - Create there a new directory with a reasonable name for you (like `my_repo`)
   - Go into that directory
   - Select from the context menu `TortoiseSVN > Create repository here`
   - The repository will be created inside that directory.
2. A directory is selected

   - Start in a directory
   - Create there a new directory with a reasonable name for you (like `my_repo`)
   - Select that new directory, but don't go into
   - Select from the context menu `TortoiseSVN > Create repository here`
   - The repository will be created inside that selected directory.

What most people do (and what does not work) is:

- Start in a not-empty directory.
- Select from the context menu `TortoiseSVN > Create repository here`
- You will get the error message you have seen.

If you look at the context menu, you will notice that there are no `...` at the end. So TortoiseSVN needs everything for the command from the calling context, there will no clarification dialog.

You will find that information in the TortoiseSVN Help file when searching for `create repository here`.